# Drawing a circle in SDL 2, but each circle uses CPU a lot

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sdl, sdl-2

i wrote a code that draw filled circle, but it uses CPU a lot.
The thing is i draw pixel by pixel, first outter circle with radius n the second circle with radius n-1 and so on while n is not equal to 0.
I'm drawing 4 pixel in e cycle, for each circle part. Every part, as i thought, has ~ Pi/(2*R) pixels, but it is not enough and circle fill wrong, so i used Pi/(4*R) and now circle fills normaly.

```
Deg0 = 0;
Deg90 = M_PI / 2;
DegStep = Deg90 / (R * 4);
CurrDeg = Deg0;
OffsetX = R;
OffsetY = 0;
TmpR = R;
while(TmpR>0 )
{
    while(CurrDeg < Deg90)
    {
        OffsetX = cos(CurrDeg) * TmpR;
        OffsetY = sin(CurrDeg) * TmpR;
        SDL_RenderDrawPoint(Renderer, CX+(int)OffsetX, CY+(int)OffsetY);
        SDL_RenderDrawPoint(Renderer, CX-(int)OffsetY, CY+(int)OffsetX);
        SDL_RenderDrawPoint(Renderer, CX-(int)OffsetX, CY-(int)OffsetY);
        SDL_RenderDrawPoint(Renderer, CX+(int)OffsetY, CY-(int)OffsetX);
        CurrDeg+=DegStep;
    }
    CurrDeg = Deg0;
    TmpR-=1;
}
```

So, is there any way to improve my realisation?

Comment: At what rate are you drawing those circles?

Comment: What do you mean? Speed?

Comment: Smells like you need the [Brezenham circle algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm).

Comment: I'm questioning whether you are drawing many circles at once in each frame, and how many frames you are drawing each second (if applicable).

Comment: Honestly, i dont know, i'm not counting frames. How could i check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the circle drawing capabilities of SDL, or you could optimize your own code by not actually using cos and sin. Use lookup tables instead.

Comment: You mean to create cin/cos table and the just use?

Comment: Yes, the actual cos and sin functions are really CPU intensive.

Comment: But i steel need to precalculate some sin/cos values, or there is another way?

Comment: Multiple options: precalculate once and generate a bin file that contains the data, statically initialize two C-arrays, or precalculate once at startup.